# mockk not working while executing entire android test package

Tags: android, junit, mockk

I have written test cases for my view model. Which **when I run individually** or when I **run the Test class**. They get executed **successfully**. But when I run the complete androidTest package, I get this **Exception**
**io.mockk.MockKException**

Here is the code that runs successfully in isolation.

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class MyViewModelTest{

    @Test
    fun test_one(){
        getInstrumentation().runOnMainSync(Runnable {
            val context = ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext<Context>()
            mockkStatic(MyManager::class)
            val myInterface = mockk<MyInterface>()
            every { MyManager.getCommunicator() } returns myInterface
            every { myInterface.context } returns context
            every { myInterface.getLongFromGTM(any()) } returns 0
            val viewModel = MyViewModel(context as Application)
            viewModel.model = MyDataModel()
            viewModel.model.isRepeatEligible = true
            val res = viewModel.isRepeatEligible()
            Truth.assertThat(res).isTrue()
        })
    }

}
```

This is the error I am getting while running entire androidTest package:

[image]

Here are the detailed used classes

1 .) **MyManager.java**

```
public class MyManager {
    private static MyInterface myCommunicator;
    
    public static MyInterface getCommunicator() {
        if (myCommunicator == null) {
            synchronized (MyManager.class) {
                if (myCommunicator == null) {
                    Class<?> cls = Class.forName("mypackage.communicator.MyCommunicator");
                    myCommunicator = (MyInterface) cls.newInstance();
                }
            }
        }
        return myCommunicator;
    }    
}
```

2.) **MyViewModel.kt**

```
class MyViewModel(application: Application) : BaseViewModel(application) {
    var model = MyDataModel()    
    private val timerDelay: Long by lazy {
        myCommunicator.getLongFromGTM("key_p2m_timer_delay")
    }
    val timerDuration: Long by lazy {
        myCommunicator.getLongFromGTM("key_p2m_timer_duration")
    }

    fun isRepeatEligible(): Boolean {
        model.apply {
            return isRepeatEligible && !isLinkBased && !isAlreadyPresent
        }
}
```

Comment: Where does the `myCommunicator` in `MyViewModel` come from? Is it something defined in `BaseViewModel`?

Comment: We have a separate class of Extension Functions, where we have this myCommunicator instance which is instantiated like this "val myCommunicator : MyInterface = MyManager.getCommunicator()"

Comment: That may be the (additional) problem. Check out the update in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mocking something with MockK is not contrained to just one function. Specifically, when you mock an object with `mockkStatic`, the object will from then on be a mock until it is unmocked using `unmockkStatic` or `unmockkAll`.

In your case, I guess the problem arises due to the static mocking of `MyManager` that lets subsequent tests fail, because they do not expect the object to be mocked.

This could be solved with an "after" function (e.g. using JUnit4, a function annotated with `@After`) that calls `unmockAll`.

Alternatively, if you want to make sure that the object is only mocked locally, you can use a variant of `mockkStatic` that accepts a block that is the only place where the object is mocked like this:

```
mockkStatic(MyManager::class) {
   // inside this block, MyManager is mocked
}
// MyManager is automatically unmocked after the block
```

###### Update

As mentioned in your comment, you do not call `MyManager.getCommunicator()` directly in `MyViewModel`, but via an extension property

```
val myCommunicator : MyInterface = MyManager.getCommunicator()
```

This may cause your test setup to be still in place after your test, even when you unmock `MyManager`, because the property `myCommunicator` will keep its value - the mocked interface.

This can be solved by changing your property to not be initialized with the value of `MyManager.getCommunicator()`, but instead you should define a getter that calls `MyManager.getCommunicator()`:

```
val myCommunicator: MyInterface get() = MyManager.getCommunicator()
```

This way, you do always get the current value of `MyManager.getCommunicator()` and not the value that was set once on initialization.

See https://kotlinlang.org/docs/properties.html#getters-and-setters for details on property getters.

Comment: I tried to put the code inside this mockkStatic block, but still there is a same problem